# Save as raw image data in Firefox

Tags: php, firefox, download

I'm using echo file_gets_content to output a raw image data jpeg based on $_POSTed variables. I get the expected result( display image) However when I "right click save as" Firefox attempts to download the file which then turns out to be corrupt

This does not happen in Google Chrome so why is this happening and how can I work around this?

Comment: corrupt how? 0-byte file? different bytes inside?

Comment: @MarcB apparently when I use notepad to open it....i see HTML markup

Comment: I'm not sure the problem might be to the fact that the request method to display image data would be via POST form....could this be the reason?

Comment: what's the html? php error messages? headers/boiler plate for your site?

Comment: @MarcB no error messaged nothing like that....

the process logic is as follows

submit a POST form with image data;
save data as file ;
output image headers;
then
readfile();

Comment: then what's the html text you're seeing inside the file? you have to figure out where that's coming from.

Comment: @MarcB no error messaged nothing like that....

the process logic is as follows

submit a POST form with image data;
save data as file ;
output image headers;
then
readfile();
the broswer displays the image;
then right click on image;
save as;
The file is downloaded via the down load manager;
The file saves as an image extension file;
But on opening the file via notepad I see html output

So i believe that Firefox is actually trying to duplicate the process but WITHOUT the POSTED variables to save the file to desktop

Comment: And WHAT IS THAT HTML YOU ARE SEEING? We cannot help you if you don't read and understand what we're asking. Forget firefox. Forget chrome. Forget everything else. OPEN THAT FILE IN NOTEPAD. TELL US WHAT THE HTML IS.

Comment: Ok sorry the HTML is the default output if no POSTED variables are sent. its simply a fail safe dummy html and doesn't have any error output messages

Comment: then look into why firefox isn't sending anything.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was right...when you "right click/ save as" in Firefox he browser attempts to download the media by replicating the process...the problem seems to be that it does not POST the variables needed to reproduce the image. Using a session in my logic resolved the issue